# Java Generics Programming with Collection

Tags: java

I have being stuck with this assignment for weeks now. I just need some help for starting.
Here is first requriment:

Design a generic container called GenericOrder that acts as a collection of an arbitrary number of objects in Products.java. Design a mechanism that gives each instance of the container a unique identifier. Implement as many methods as necessary. You must use Java generics features.

Here is what I have, I don't if I did right or not. The instructor says, this GenericOrder must use collection to hold multiple "Product".

```
public class GenericOrder<T> {
    private T theProduct;
    private static int count = 1;
    private final int orderNumber = count++;
    private Collection<T> genCollection;

    public GenericOrder(T theClass)
    {
        this.theProduct = theClass;
    }

    public String getProductID()
    {
     return theProduct.getClass().getName() + ": " + orderNumber;
    }

    public T createInstance()
    throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        return this.theProduct;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's your question? Are you asking if your `class` satisfies the assignment?

Comment: Seems to me that you're mixing the product and the container in some strange way.. For what do you need 'theProduct' and all methods that meddle with it someway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Design a generic container called GenericOrder that acts as a collection of an arbitrary number of objects

Rather change your container to include what @pst suggested.

> Design a mechanism that gives each instance of the container a unique identifier.

Here you got it almost right. But your general thinking was correct.

```
public class GenericOrder<T> {
    private static int ID = 0;
    private String serial;
    List<T> products;

    public GenericOrder() {
        serial = "CONTAINER_" + ID++;
        products = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public String getUniqueSerial() {
        return serial;
    }

    public void addProduct(T newProduct) {
        products.add(newProduct);
    }

    public int getNumberOfProducts() {
        return products.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your replying. I will double check with Instructor with your code. This is a distance learning course, so it's very hard for me to ask questions to Instructor

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine there can be multiple "products" per "order":

```
public class GenericOrder<T> {
  List<T> productsOrdered ...
  public GenericOrder(List<T> products) {
     ...
  }
}
```

But I really have no idea how generics are supposed to help with that, and I can't honestly "piece together" the assignment from just that context so, YMMV.

Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

I might be all wrong here, but it sounds to me like you should inherit from Collection. And for the unique identifier I would perhaps use a map.

Comment: I don't think he has to inherit `Collection`. He's description says it has to *act as a collection*. The unique identifier refers to identifying the containers. To use a `Map` you will still need to know the keys.